# Instead of using 54W 6500K T5's, can I use 54W 5000K T5's?

Tags: grow-lamp

I want to buy some T5's for indoor planting. The specifications I found until now are 54W and 6500K. In a nearby shop, I found 54W with 5000K. I've been reading [this](https://www.waveformlighting.com/art-painting/difference-between-5000k-and-6500k-bulbs) and there is the following graphic:

[image]

It seems that 5000K lamps have ~71% of the total blue of 6400K lamps (taking the measurement from 430nm, the rest of the measurements in the blue zone seems to be roughly at the same ratio). The difference for reds doesn't seems to be big. But I don't know if it makes a big impact on the plants. I've been searching for YT videos on people planting with 5000K lamps but it seems everybody uses only 6500K.

Comment: If no answer comes up, you can also ask on Biology SE. I hope you'll have more luck there.